# $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }u^{n-1}=\frac{1}{1-u}$ is available for all cases?

Tags: calculus, summation

I don't understand this equal $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }u^{n-1}=\frac{1}{1-u}$ . I verify all value and don't get $\frac{1}{1-u}$ Please explain why we obtain that equal. I obtain $\frac{1-u^n}{1-u}$ because I think is geometric series, am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the pictorial proof that $1+r+r^2+\ldots=\frac{1}{1-r}$

[image: The pictorial proof]

Answer (score 2):

$LHS = \displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n u^{k-1} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{1-u^n}{1-u} =\dfrac{1}{1-u}$, for $|u| < 1$ since $u^n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

It is a geometric series, and so your version is correct, and the infinite sum is only correct when $|u|<1$. This is because $$\lim_{n \to \infty} u^n=0$$ when $|u|<1$, so therefore:
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1-u^n}{1-u}=\frac{1}{1-u}$$

Answer (score 2):

We have:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\color{red}k u^{n-1}=\frac{1-u^\color{red}k}{1-u}$$
due to it being a geometric series.

Notice that the exponent, in the answer, is $k$ rather than $n$. This is because $n$ is a *dummy variable*, and $k$ is the one that actually affects the sum.

Letting $k$ go to infinity, we have:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty u^{n-1}=\frac1{1-u}$$
as long as $-1<u<1$. That's because, if $\lvert u\rvert<1$, $\lim_{k\to\infty}u^k=0$.

Comment: Also, if you start it at $n=0$ instead of $n=1$, it looks nicer. $\sum_{n=0}^\infty u^n=1/(1-u)$